# Why is there no univerbation with Italian's "con te"?

Tags: univerbation

"With you" in Latin is *tecum*; in Spanish, *contigo*; but in Italian, why is it two separate words, *con te* (no [univerbation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/univerbation))?

Comment: Actually, univerbation exists also in Italian: *teco*, *meco*. But it is ancient or literary https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/teco/

Comment: @BakerStreet Why did _teco_ fall into disuse?

Comment: I don't know, I remember only having  heard *teco* in some prayer (Ave Maria) and in literature.

Comment: I believe that “meco” e “teco” are literary latinisms, never used in spoken language.

Comment: Per approfondimenti sugli usi e numerosi esempi, vedi qui, a p. 793: https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol-xx/20

Comment: In literature, I've heard of  "seco"  for "with self"

Comment: @Geremia Why? Just because. Some words and forms just fall in disuse, probably because the alternatives are more common and consistent, like the use of prepositions in this case (which also has some archaic forms that are normally avoided, like "colla" instead of "con la"). "Meco" and "teco" remain valid and acceptable mostly because of their literary usage (poetry and opera), but normally restricted to those fields (if not for sarcastic/comedic purposes).

Answer (score 3):

In realtà l'univerbazione esiste anche in italiano: *teco*. Ma il suo uso è antico o letterario.

Usi e numerosi esempi:

[image]

<sup>Sorgente: [il commento di DaG](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/14463/why-is-there-no-univerbation-with-italians-con-te?noredirect=1#comment35420_14463)</sup>